# Dialogflow doesn't recognise certain words in training phrases

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have created a number of intents and for the most part, they're all working well and by that I mean, it identifies the correct intent and the sentiment score is as expected.

However, there are a couple of words that exist on the intent training phrases, but dialogflows sentiment score is negative. On the example below "Missing" appears to be the issue. When i use the same phrase and replace "Missing" for "Wrong" it also gives me a negative response.

These 3 items are currently on the intent as training phrases:

1. proactive is missing (fails)
2. proactive is wrong (fails)
3. proactive is correct (pass)

Any ideas? i'm starting to think dialogflow is a very positive bot :-)

```
`

{
  "responseId": "1232141231231",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "proactive is missing",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/my-projectid/agent/intents/dialog-value-here",
      "displayName": "question one"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en",
    "sentimentAnalysisResult": {
      "queryTextSentiment": {
        "score": -0.8,
        "magnitude": 0.8
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

After doing some reading on various ways of creating coherent conversations, I came across [this article from google](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/assessing-the-quality-of-training-phrases-in-dialogflow-intents). My key takeaways from it are:

1. Cohesion: The average similarity value between each pair of phrases in the same intent. That value is computed for each intent. The higher the intent cohesion value, the better the intent training phrases.
2. Separation: Given two intents, the average distance between each pair of training phrases in the two intents.
3. Confusing phrases: Training phrases that are highly similar to training phrases in other intents.

Though I wasn't able to fix my current issue, it helped me understand why the bot gets confused, pretty much out of context from all other training phrases.

If anyone has any thoughts or recommendations, i'd really appreciate it.